# npm - tarball data for material-design-icons seems to be corrupted

Tags: npm, material-design

I'm having this error while running a `npm install material-design-icons@3.0.1`:

```
tarball data for material-design-icons@3.0.1 (sha1-mnHEh0chjrylHlGmbaaCA4zct78=) seems to be corrupted
npm ERR! path D:\speech-analytics\node_modules\.staging\material-design-icons-7d5a1f73\action\drawable-xxhdpi\ic_assignment_ind_white_48dp.png
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'D:\\speech-analytics\node_modules\.staging\material-design-icons-7d5a1f73\action\drawable-xxhdpi\ic_assignment_ind_white_48dp.png'
npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'D:\\speech-analytics\node_modules\.staging\material-design-icons-7d5a1f73\action\drawable-xxhdpi\ic_assignment_ind_white_48dp.png'
```

[Here](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/issues/853) it's documented as a bug, but still without an answer nor a fix.

I've tried to reinstall node, upgraded to latest npm version (currently running 6.4.1), did a `cache clean --force`, tried a `npm install --no-optional`, removed `package-lock.json`, removed `npm` & `npm-cache` folders from AppData directory, running everything as Administrator, but still no luck.

I even tried with material-design-icons@3.0.0 but the error remains.

If I navigate to the folder that appears in the log (`node_modules\.staging\material-design-icons-7d5a1f73\action\drawable-xxhdpi`), it's empty, and is the only folder that exists in the entire node_modules directory. I can delete that dir without any problems, so it does not seem to be a permissions/lock issue.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Finally, I got this fixed by:

- Removing `node_modules` folder
- Running `npm update`
- Running `npm install`

As far I understand, the [npm update](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update) should have updated the package.json file, but all dependencies kept the same versions as we had it before.

Comment: I ran into this exact same problem, same symptoms, on a fresh machine.  For me, the `cache clean --force` did the trick.  Thanks for posting!

Answer (score 13):

I resolved this with the command: `npm cache verify` which output:

```
Cache verified and compressed (C:\Programs\DCPS\npm-cache\_cacache):
Content verified: 1344 (164824963 bytes)
Content garbage-collected: 1 (3491551 bytes)
Index entries: 1522
Finished in 8.187s
```

The line that stands out to me is: **Content garbage-collected: 1 (3491551 bytes)**

Does this sort of thing happen because a new version of a package is published to npmjs without a version bump?

Comment: Thanks for this one, could have saved me quite a bit of time.

Answer (score 10):

No need to run npm update (I didn't want to update any packages) or delete the entire `node_modules` folder.  I solved this by

1. deleting `package-lock.json`
2. deleting `node_modules\material-design-icons-xxxxxxx`
3. running `npm install` again

Comment: Deleting package-lock.json was the solution for me.

Answer (score 4):

If `npm update` is not a solution, and as deleting `package-lock.json` can bring issues of its own, I could solve it simply by:

- deleting the `node_modules/` folder
- in `package-lock.json`, deleting the sections referencing to the corrupted package
- running `npm install` again

Comment: I was using a library from a private registry and I changed the code without updating the version as it's still in dev, leaving my `package-lock.json` with a bad `integrity` property. Deleting the corresponding section solved the issue and sounds like a better practice than deleting the whole file.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on windows env, I fixed it by running the cmd as administrator

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers solved my problem, because in my case was the git. Maybe someone can have the same problem.

I had some dependencies from git in the project and my git was not working on the terminal. So fixing the path for git fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

You need to confirm whether the Typescript is installed and after installing typescript it worked for me

running the below comment will show the typescript version

```
tsc -v
```

If it shows some error install the typescript

```
npm install -g typescript
```

If then typescript is installed you can try checking the Angular Cli version

```
ng --version
```

If it shows some error then install Angular Cli Ref: https://cli.angular.io/

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Answer (score 0):

" If you are on windows env, I fixed it by running the cmd as administrator "

- This worked for me. However, chromedriver was not installed. So, i installed it separately using the command 'npm install chromedriver'.

Answer (score 0):

I had this in Bitbucket Pipeline when using a private package.

I was missing to install git in pipeline:

```
script:
  - apk update && apk upgrade && apk add --no-cache bash git openssh # <- THIS
  - npm ci --prefer-offline
```

Dependency was

```
"some-private-package": "git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/workspace/some-private-package#v1.0.12",`
```

Answer (score -2):

Well I could not resolve this problem with a lot of tries so I made the download of the github ZIP, unzip and install and it worked !

```
download material-design-icons from github
unzip to the directory of your project (or c:\tmp) 
npm install  ./material-design-icons
```

or

```
npm install  c:/tmp/material-design-icons
```